# I do not understand how I can fix is error

Tags: java, swing

So I'm writing this code for an assignment I have due tomorrow. I need to input a number and then see if its even and a single digit number. I know where my error is, but I do not have the slightest idea of how to fix this error. Could you guys help me out? Here's the code:

```
package favoritenumber;  
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   

public class FavoriteNumber {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x;
        x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your favorite number?");
        Integer.parseInt(x);        
        boolean Even = isEven ();
        boolean Digit = isSingleDigit ();
        System.out.println (Even);
        System.out.println (Digit);
        if (Even && Digit) {
            System.out.println ("Wow, your number is even and a single digit.");
        }


    }

    public static boolean isEven (int x) {
        boolean evenFlag;
        if (x%2 == 0) {
            evenFlag = true;            
        } else {
            evenFlag = false;
        }
        return evenFlag;
    }

    public static boolean isSingleDigit (int x) {
        boolean digitFlag;
        if (x > -9 && x < 9)  {
            digitFlag = true;     
        } else {
            digitFlag = false;
        }
        return digitFlag;
    }


}
```

I;m getting the error at 
boolean Even = isEven ();
and 
boolean Digit = isSingleDigit ();

Comment: You need to have parameters in your methods. What you want to do is `isEven(Integer.parseInt(x))` and `isSingleDigit(Integer.parseInt(x))`.

Comment: Do you know what arguments do? Your instructors better teach you about something and how to use/how it works before you actually use it.

Comment: If you look at the error you are getting it will plainly tell you `The method isEven(int) in the type .... is not applicable for the arguments ()` meaning you are passing nothing into a method that you explicitly said needs an int.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you successfully got the number form user then you did Integer.parseInt(x); You didn't assign the result to any variable. Then you called         boolean Even = isEven (); boolean Digit = isSingleDigit (); methods but you didn't pass any value. If you look at your method declaration they are expecting int argument public static boolean isEven (int x){...}, public static boolean isSingleDigit (int x) {...}. Hope this helps! PS. don't get frustrated, read that error message says and most of the time you will be able to figure out. Good luck!